# Div css position and overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css

placing a div inside  div and on scroll of outer div applying css 
'position': 'fixed' to the inner div and  when i began to scroll the outer div, the inner div is just appearing above the outer div with its own width and height

How can i just avoid the div overflow ?

**my sample code:**

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="masterdiv" style="width:50%;height:25%;margin:0 auto;overflow: scroll;"> 
       <div class="scroller_anchor" style="height:0px; margin:0; padding:0;"></div>
       <div class="scroller" style="background:#FFF; border:1px solid #CCC; margin:0 0 10px; z-index:100; height:50px; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:960px;">This is the scrolSuspendisse potenti. Donec dapibus tlable bar</div>
       <div class="test_content">Quisque sollicitudin elit vitae</div>
   </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
$('#masterdiv').scroll(function(e) {
    var scroller_anchor = $(".scroller_anchor").offset().top;    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'fixed') 
    {  
         $('.scroller').css({            
             'position': 'absolute',
             'overflow': 'hidden',
             'top': '0px'
         });       
         $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '50px');
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < scroller_anchor && $('.scroller').css('position') != 'relative') 
    {  
         $('.scroller_anchor').css('height', '0px');        
         $('.scroller').css({
              'background': '#FFF',
              'border': '1px solid #CCC',
              'overflow': 'hidden',
              'position': 'absolute'
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want the inside element to go outside of the container element when scrolled down and stay fixed right above it?

Comment: you can use z-index to show div over other div instead of position attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Because you make the inner div position fixed, the div will stay where it is on the screen, doesn't matter where the outer div is.